# List OrderBy Value < Value

Tags: c#, list, linq, expression, sql-order-by

I got a list with a class that holds prices (lowest, average, highest).
Now I want to order the list:

1. lowest < average = first entries | all others after those entries ordered by lowest
2. the lowest < average entries ordered by highest difference between lowest and average

**Example:**

```
(unordered: low,avg,high)

{1, 2, 5}

{4, 3, 7}

{2, 5, 6}

{2, 1, 3}

(ordered: low,avg,high)

{2, 5, 6} -> highest difference between low < avg

{1, 2, 5} -> low < avg

{2, 1, 3} -> lowest low while low > avg

{4, 3, 7} -> ...
```

This is probably a pretty easy thing to do but I'm getting a headache when I think about it. I tried to use .OrderBy and .GroupBy but I can't get it to work.

Comment: A bit strange that the average can by lower than the lowest! 

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Well with the known informations this is true. But if you think about a software that is analysing a market it isn't strange at all. Just think about it: You scanned the market like 50 times and the average is $10. Now someone buys all the items and lists them for $20. So the next scan you do the average is below the lowest available price.

Comment: I don't know much about markets. You are challenging my life-long beliefs about what "lowest" really means!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias the lowest available price at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Average - x.Lowest).ThenBy(x => x.Lowest).ToList();
```

Considering your class will look like

```
public class price
{
   int Lowest {get; set;}
   int Average {get; set;}
   int Highest  {get; set;}
}
```

Now you want Order list of Price by condition `Average - Lowest`

```
List<Price> prices = new List<Price>();
```

then you can sort it by

```
var sortedList = prices.OrderByDescending(x => (x.Average - x.Lowest)).ThenBy(x => x.Lowest).ToList();
```

POC : [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ees8SE)

Comment: Will not work.  It gets the item closest to the average but may be higher when ops wants lowest.

Comment: You edited the answer after my comment.  So know it is working.

Comment: @Myridor If it works then please accept my answer with green tick